# Is $\langle a,b\; |\;a^7 = 1, ab = b^3a^3\rangle$ finite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I've been playing a little with group definitions to see what kind of things I can make up. I'm struggling to prove that this group is finite. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: The elements generated by $b$ form a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Henry Can you prove that? Is there a way to spot this, that would also immediately spot that in $\langle a,b|a^3=1,bab=a\rangle$, the element $b$ has order $2$, for example?

Comment: I have no idea if this particular group is finite or not: Such problem is in general undecidable. Take a look at GAP http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap47.html bottom of the page for how to check finiteness or infiniteness of a group in practice.

Comment: $G_n = \langle a,b | a^n = 1, ab=b^3 a^3 \rangle$ is finite solvable when $n \in \{1,2,3,5,6\}$ and has an infinite solvable quotient $n=4$. If $G_7$ is solvable, it is isomorphic to $C_2 \times (C_7 \ltimes C_{43})$. If $G_9$ is solvable, it is isomorphic to $C_2 \times (C_9 \ltimes C_{109})$.

Comment: $G_1=C_2$, $G_2 = QD_{16}$, $G_3 = C_6$, $G_5 = C_2 \times ( C_5 \ltimes C_11)$, $|G_6| = 2^4 3^4 7$, $G_8$ has an infinite solvable quotient. $G_{10}$ has a large solvable quotient ($2^4 \cdot 5 \cdot 11^2$, unclear if it has a larger solvable quotient). If $G_{11}$ is solvable, then it is $C_2 \times (C_{11} \ltimes C_{397})$. $G_{12}$ has an infinite solvable quotient.

Answer (score 3):

This group is infinite, but the proof was a lengthy computer calculation which proved it automatic and found the automatic structure, so I am afraid you might not find that totally satisfactory. The order of $b$ is indeed infinite.